# is it better to create periodic events using RegisterCacheEntry in Global.asax.cs or Timer start() and stop()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

Can anyone provide the better option between RegisterCacheEntry in Global.asax.cs and Timer?

RegisterCacheEntry() example

```
    private void RegisterCacheEntry()
    {
        // Prevent duplicate key addition
        if (null != HttpContext.Current.Cache[Dummy_CacheItem]) return;

        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(Dummy_CacheItem, "Test", null, DateTime.MaxValue,
            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,
            new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemovedCallback));
    }

    public void CacheItemRemovedCallback(
        string key,
        object value,
        CacheItemRemovedReason reason
        )
    {
           // call the function to be run periodically
    }
```

Timer example
http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Timer-Objects-in-Windows-Services-with-C-NET/

Please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of them, go make a windows service and use a timer.

To user the object cache as a timer is serious misuse, and will make you code a lot less readable. Also remember that the timer will only run when the application pool is active, and you have no control over when the pool is being recycled.

Answer (score 0):

To run a task at specific interval, you should use the Windows Task Scheduler. Write a  console application and create the scheduled task.

This solution is simplier than writing a windows service and provides more options about when the task should run.